# How I can filter a datatable using a html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, filter, datatable

Is it possible to perform this? I want a field search for my datatable. I created 3 field as search options. I'm using a postgresql my database.

I checked the datatables plugin. They have the field filter that I wanted but I would be better if I can put the fields outside the datatable itself..

UPDATE: I just found out it is possible. I had the code and I'm getting an error `DataTables warning: table_id = store_table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.`

This is what I've got so far:

My javascript that perform the multiple individual filtering:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// DataTable
var dtable = $('#store_table').DataTable();

$('.search-button').on('click', function () {
    //clear global search values
    dtable.search('');
    $('.filter').each(function(){ 
    if(this.value.length){
      dtable.column($(this).data('columnIndex')).search(this.value);
    }
    });
    dtable.draw();
});

$( ".dataTables_filter input" ).on( 'keyup change',function() {
   //clear column search values
    dtable.columns().search('');
   //clear input values
   $('.filter').val('');
    }); 

});
```

The form from my html that should filter the data

```
<form class="form-search">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="shop_no" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Shop#</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control filter" id="shopNo" value='' data-column-index='0'/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="shop_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Shop Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control filter" id="shopName" value='' data-column-index='3'/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="shop_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label filter" value=''>Shop Kind</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle filter" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-column-index='2'>Select </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item filter" href="#">The Suite Company</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item filter" href="#">Universal Language</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item filter" href="#">OUT LET</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning search-button">Search</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: yes it is possible